# Blog and Static Pages in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, blogs

I would like to add static pages to an existing rails 4.0 app. These page such as About, Contact and help to be like this:
examble.com/about

Also, I want to add a blog engine to publish news:

The first type is static and won't be change. However, the second type which is the news, I'd like to add posts using a form so all the admins can add posts easily.

I looked to different gems for example Jekyll does not allow add posts using a form if I want to add I have to write codes and create files.

So what is your suggestions please?

Regards,

Comment: if it's just a simple static about page you don't need a gem.  just use `rails g controller static` and then set up your routes file accordingly.  If the page is going to get updated every so often, then create a view and action as you normally would in an existing controller.

Comment: What I want is a semi-static page where pages are stored in database so it can be edited by admin users. I am asking if there is such thing ready so I don't bother creating from scratch.

Comment: fork that : https://github.com/lkdjiin/blog and just add a "contact" and "help" method in the PagesController.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do is set up a separate blog server (let's say using wordpress) and point the DNS for blog.example.com to the ip address of your blog server.

Then you can give individual users accounts on the blog, so that they can upload content.

I would suggest using an existing blog engine such as wordpress (there are several others) because out of the box it will include a bunch of stuff like image uploading, tagging, comments, antispam, and SEO optimizations like pretty permalinks. I wouldn't rebuild that from scratch.

If you want the blog to reside at www.example.com/blog, then there is a bit of a trick to configure the web server to serve up content from two different servers, but that's certainly not impossible.